# Japanese book about an infinite loop?

Tags: story-identification, books

My sister sent me a book 15 years ago that she now doesn't remember sending, and I can't recall the title.

It is about a few things. If I remember correctly, there is a female character who lives with some sort of relative or mentor figure, and the two choose not to read or write anything, since they think that committing ideas to paper will neuter their memories. There may or may not also be a chase.

And, most memorably, there is a character who dies, only to find that he's in some sort of endless loop or liminal space that just keeps going. Maybe a village of some sort? It seems to be implied that it's a hallucination of a dying brain right before the lights go out, but that the hallucination just. Keeps. Going.

Anyhow, hopefully someone can help me out with a possible title or two.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this a spatial loop (leaving town just puts him at the other edge) or a temporal one (after some period of time, the period of time starts again)?

Comment: And can you elaborate on the fantasy or sci-fi aspects? It sounds like you're provided the non-fantastic explanation for the looping town.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! There's definitely some sort of sci-fi part going on in the form of the woman (girl?) and her mentor/relative figure. I forget what they're researching, but they're doing some sort of research -- maybe in a large, dark space of some sort? As far as the loop goes, I actually don't remember whether it's temporal or spacial or both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The novel is called [*Hard-Boiled Wonderland and the End of the World*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?12354) by Haruki Murakami ([Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard-Boiled_Wonderland_and_the_End_of_the_World)).

Now I'm looking forward to reading it to see if it's even close to the plot I remembered.

Comment: Glad you found it. Please don't forget to mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].